# Rake routes fails with Access denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to run the rake routes command on my remote site, and I get the error message  **Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

The site can access the database, so it's not the settings in database.yml, but it has recently started throwing up **Action not found** errors after months of working OK. Any thoughts on how I can see the routes so that I can check nothing has been corrupted?

Rails 3.2.3, Ruby 1.8.7, Phusion Passenger.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and just resolved it by setting proper development database configuration options in config/database.yml
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database:
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock